# CSS & HTML drop down in Blogger --- Not behaving when hovering in IE; but perfect in other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, blogger

I'm adding a drop down menu bar to my blog using html & CSS.

The code is from [My Blogger Lab](http://www.mybloggerlab.com/2012/05/animated-css3-multi-drop-down-menu-for.html) with tweaks to color etc.

My test site is: http://practicedailygratitude.blogspot.com/

I'm 100% happy with the way it looks in Chrome & Firefox (drop downs are really only for About, Images, and Home DIY; the rest are just links).

I'm having the following issues in IE (I tried 7, 8 and 64-bit):

1. In Explorer, the drop downs are showing up with almost a transparent background (I can see the post's text behind them)
2. In Explorer the drop down happens so quickly that I can't hover or pick a choice.
3. In safari, links aren't active and the drop downs down appear on the hover.

I've been searching for two weeks and trying different tweaks & suggestions from other posts but I don't know how to make it work in IE.

I don't use IE, but 30+% of her blog followers do, so I need to make adjustments, I'm just totally out of ideas (and I've reached my competency) at this point.

I've been able to adjust the code to get it exactly how I want it (with the drop downs hovering over the flag banner in the header) in Chrome & Firefox.

Note: This code requires the html gadget to be put at the top of the blog post section, not the header, so that's why I've changed some margins etc. to get the drop downs to move and "look right" with the header image behind it.

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

The theme is SIMPLE from Blogger by Josh Peterson.  It's one of the few choices in Blogger ---- I haven't modified it; I'm only modifying through 1 html widget I added above the post section and then there is an advanced CSS tab for the template ---- that's where I went to Advanced and then "add CSS" and added the CSS from My Blogger Lab (only updating the colors and moving so it would overlay the header) ---- it appears that the CSS then adds itself in the SIMPLE template.

html for widget: http://practicedailygratitude.blogspot.com/2012/09/my-blogger-lab-html-code-for-widget.html

CSS:  http://practicedailygratitude.blogspot.com/2012/09/my-blogger-labs-css-i-modified-for.html

Simple template in Blogger    http://practicedailygratitude.blogspot.com/2012/10/simple-template-from-blogger.html

Comment: It works for me on IE, no matter the version. Be sure you are not in quirks mode. (F12 to check that)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Caelea.  

I checked and I'm in IE 7 standards.

I'm attaching a screenshot above ---- the drop down appears (sometimes) then immediately when I try to make a choice.  It's also showing an alt tag in IE that doesn't show in other browsers.  I still can't hover or select anything from the drop down ---- it goes away too quickly.

I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong that it works in IE for you, but doesn't for me.  What DOC TYPE should I be using?  Could it have something to do with that? Thank you.

Comment: This needs to be closed as too-localized. If your question can't be asked without images or links to external sites, it can't be asked here. We should not have to open your website and inspect its source to answer your question.

Comment: @Emily M The doctype is ok, and there is not much you can do, after all it's blogspot and you can't change it so it has something to do with the plugin used for that menu. Unfortunately I'm ot that good at javascript. I hope somebody will help you better than I did.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code and it first needs to be cleaned up. By cleanup, I mean syntax errors in your markup: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpracticedailygratitude.blogspot.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

There are quite a few errors here which might be causing the issue you are experiencing.

If you still see the problem after the cleanup, you should probably approach it as a regular z-index issue on IE7. This can be solved if you put `position: relative;` and `z-index: 500;` on all the parent elements that contain the menu. So, go `div` by `div` and add the `position` and `z-index` rules. Since your menu has a `z-index` value of `500`, its parents must have a defined value for that rule as well, which needs to be equal or greater than the child element - in this case the menu. This will solve the issue with the menu going behind the content (I already tested it on the current state of the site).

On a side note, you have the following tag declared on your page: `<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>`. What this does is force Internet Explorer 8+ to render the page using the IE7 compatibility mode. I think you want this tag removed.

Let me know if this helped you out.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this today and let you know!

Comment: Thanks! I tried for hours. I think the errors refer to the original blogger template or the html or CSS for the widget that I copied directly. I've tried to go through, but I don't think I'm skilled enough to make the edits. When I tried to make edits in the blogger template I crashed it. I tried to update the Z-index&positions (do you mean edit the CSS & add in properties for any elements (like the post body, post header) that show up on top of the drop down, or just do it for existing menu elements?) Only when the blog post is moved down, did the drop downs let me hover/select in IE. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't be of more help without access to the files. Did you build this theme or have you downloaded it somewhere?

Comment: The theme is SIMPLE from Blogger by Josh Peterson.  It's one of the few choices in Blogger ---- I haven't modified it; I'm only modifying through 1 html widget I added above the post section and then there is an advanced CSS tab for the template ---- that's where I went to Advanced and then "add CSS" and added the CSS from My Blogger Lab (only updating the colors and moving so it would overlay the header) ---- it appears that the CSS then adds itself in the SIMPLE template.

Comment: html for widget: http://practicedailygratitude.blogspot.com/2012/09/my-blogger-lab-html-code-for-widget.html

CSS:  http://practicedailygratitude.blogspot.com/2012/09/my-blogger-labs-css-i-modified-for.html

Simple template in Blogger:    http://practicedailygratitude.blogspot.com/2012/10/simple-template-from-blogger.html